# How could Lakṣmaṇa's mantra to kill Indrajit really work?

Tags: mantras, weapon, lakshmana, indrajit

Some folks consider [the following śloka](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga90/yuddharoman90.htm#Verse71) uttered by Lakṣmaṇa to be the mūla-mantra of Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa.

> धर्मात्मा सत्यसन्धश्च रामो दाशरथिर्यदि || ९०-६-७१ 
>   पौरुषे चाप्रतिद्वन्द्वस्तदेनं जहि रावणिम् |
>
> dharmātmā satyasandhaśca rāmo dāśarathiryadi || 90-6-71 
>   pauruṣe cāpratidvandvastadenaṃ jahi rāvaṇim |
>
> O my dear arrow! If Rama the son of Dasaratha has set his mind on virtue, keeps up his promise and is second to none in his prowess, destroy this Indrajit.

My question is not why this is considered the mūla-mantra but more to do with the how could such a mantra really work. I mean if Warrior A draws up his weapon against Warrior B and prays – "if Warrior C is a dhārmic person, let my weapon kill B" – logically, how is that supposed to work?

E.g., if Indrajit also drew a weapon and uttered a similar mantra that's based on Rāma's virtues and truthfulness and launches it on Lakṣmaṇa, will it work?

The following example, where Sītā [prays](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga53/sundarasans53.htm#Verse28) to Agni-deva to be gentle on Hanumān's burning tail, seems more logical to me because she's praying and counting on *her own* chastity (pātivratya) instead of someone else's.

> "**If I have** done any service to my husband, **if I have** performed a penance and if I am a faithful wife, please be cool to Hanuma." <sup>[5-53-28]</sup>
>
> "If the wise Rama has even a little of kindness to me and **if I have** still some good fortune remaining to my credit, please be cool to Hanuma." <sup>[5-53-29]</sup>
>
> "If that virtuous Rama recognises me as one, who is endowed with a good moral conduct and who is ardently desirous of meeting him, please be cool to Hanuma." <sup>[5-53-30]</sup>

Given the above more logical example, how to make sense of Lakṣmaṇa's prayer before he killed Indrajit?

Comment: i somewhere read that he had received some astra mantra in dream.

Answer (score 1):

As per adhyatma Ramayana by Thunjathu Ezhuthachan in Malayalam, lakshmana killed Indrajith using Aindrasthra, an astra which has Indra as the devata. Before using this astra,he prayed to the lotus feet of Lord Rama. This version of Ramayana has an independent standing and its english translation is available [here](http://www.celextel.org/stotras/vishnu/adhyatmaramayanam.html). As per kamba ramayana, the astra used had a crescent shaped tip. see [here](http://englishkambaramayanam.blogspot.com/2015/01/kamba-ramayanam-yudha-kandam-11.html). As per these ramayans, no mantra was used. Further Mythologies never explain logical issues or how equipments/ technologies, mentioned in the myth, actually work. Every issue in mythology will become a question if logical explanation is sought.

Comment: Welcome although your answer is nice but on this site we have to mention the full source of sources we have cited in answer in above case "adhyatma Ramayana" Pls,mention the  chapter /verse no etc. in answer. preferably with links or any indirect sources from where you came to know about this info.  As only name of the scriptures is not merely meet the standards of the site.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar added my source.1.The question however does not mention acharyas/websites, who consider this  sloka to be mul- mantra. 2.logic is the reasoning conducted according to strict principles of validity. Regarding Sitadevi's prayer to be logical, the strict principles of validity involved, is not mentioned by question. Instead it appears logical to the questioner. Is it not logical speculation, in the sense that the basis of this logic is subjective? --contd below--

Comment: @SwiftPushkar 3. Question requires the logic of lakshman's prayer to be atleast "as logical" as Sita devi's prayer? When we do not have strict principles of validity of logic of Sita devi's prayer, how can Lakshman's prayer be compared to it?  Request to review question on basis of the  standards of the site.

Comment: bdw in Valmiki Ramayana too Lakshman used Aindrastra to kill Indrajit...